# What the negative impacts of setting ImeMode to Off

Tags: .net, winforms, internationalization

I've got a Winforms application that I am in the process of translating into Chinese. I've got a numeric text box that validates the input with a regular expression. When the user is entering text with IME, numeric digits don't seem to come in as numeric digits.

On possible work around I have found is to set the ImeMode property of the text box to 'Off'. In my testing, this makes everything correctly, but I don't have a ton of experiance with IMEs.

What are the negative impacts of setting the ImeMode to Off? Is this something I should avoid at all costs or is it ok if the only things the user can enter are numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.imemode%28VS.85%29.aspx), it is OK to turn off the IME for a numeric field.

> An IME is a program that enables users
>   to enter complex characters and
>   symbols, such as Japanese Kanji
>   characters, using a standard keyboard.
>   The ImeMode property is typically set
>   to ImeMode.Off for a TextBox control
>   that is intended to only enter numeric
>   values.