# How to set Indic IME mode to particular TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, translation, ime

I am developing application for government where user will enter text in English and the translated text will be appeared in another textbox.

To translate the text I am using [Microsoft Indic Language Input Tool](http://www.bhashaindia.com/ilit/hindipreinstall.aspx).

So, what I want that the text should be translated(Hindi) to another textbox when I enter text in one textbox(English).

But, the problem is that the tool is creating layer on textbox so, I don't get any KeyPress/KeyDown/TextChange event until word is not completed and the IME mode is set for all input controls instead of particular single one.

Is it possible to set IME mode for only one textbox?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two `TextBox` controls, then the English only `TextBox` just needs its `ImeMode` property set to `Disable`.

E.g.

```
        this.textBox2.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.Disable;
```

(this was generated into the `Form1.Designer.cs` when I set the `Disable` via Properties pane in Visual Studio during my testing of `Form1 [Design]` mode)

**Edit:**
The above was tested to work on Windows 10 with English as my default system language.

*Interesting observation:* When I tested using `ImeMode.Off` rather than `ImeMode.Disable` (based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2209587/7270462), using `ImeMode.Off` did not seem sufficient in preventing the TextBox from accepting IME text input for a different language (tested Chinese and Japanese input and these at least still could be entered into the textbox). Also tested setting `ImeMode.NoControl` initially out of curiosity, but this also didn't achieve the same goal as `ImeMode.Disable` did.